# Accessing variables and functions from QGIS in Qt Designer

Tags: qgis, qfield, qt-designer

When I am using the QGIS built-in formula to create a formula (for QField), I can use functions and access variables like `now()` or `$y`:

[image: QGIS]

How can I access them using Qt Designer?

I want to display the current time and position within a label:

[image: Qt]

Comment: There ist no code. I am not developing a plugin. I have an attribute table and integrate the UI file with a file dialog in QGis. I don't know where to add code, there is none.

Answer (score 2):

To do that, find the object name of the QLineEdit or QLabel. You can also set the object name on Qt Designer. For instance, if you want to set now() to an QLineEdit widget, use:

```
import datetime
self.my_lineedit_objectname.setValue(datetime.datetime.now())`
```

If you want to set it to QLabel widget.
`self.my_label_objectname.setText(datetime.datetime.now())`

Replace `my_lineedit_objectname` and `my_label_objectname` with the actual object name in the UI file.
You can assign any variable in place of `datetime.datetime.now()`.

Comment: Did not help. I built my UI file with Qt Designer and then load it into QGIS. I don't see any Python code.

Comment: Are you trying to create a python plugin or C++?

Comment: You need to add the code that shows how you are integrating the UI file into QGIS.